# anchor tag is not working without href in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to perform remove operation in font awesome icon using anchor tag and js. Database used is mongodb.I am trying to use anchor tag without href. but link is not working how can I do that?

show.ejs

```html
                
    <% for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++){%>           
        <tr>
            <td> <%=i+1 %> </td>
            <td> <%= users[i].name %> </td>
            
            <td> <%= users[i].quantity %> </td>
            
            <td>
            <a  class="btn border-shadow delete" data-id=<%= users[i]._id%>>
            <span class="text-gradient"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
            </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
<%}%>
```

js file

```js
if(window.location.pathname == "/"){
    console.log('hi');
    $ondelete = $(".table tbody td a.delete");
    $ondelete.click(function(){
        var id= $(this).attr("data-id");

        var request = {
            "url" : `http://localhost:5050/addtocart/${id}`,
            "method" : "DELETE"
            
        }

        if(confirm("Do you really want to delete this record?")){
            
            $.ajax(request).done(function(response){
                alert("Data Deleted Successfully!");
                location.reload();
            })
    }
})
}
```

nodejs delete request function:

```js
exports.delete = (req,res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    Userdb.findByIdAndDelete(id)
    .then(data => {
        if(!data){
            res.status(404).send({ message : `Cannot Delete with id ${id}. Maybe id is wrong`})
        }else{
            res.send({
                message : "Item was deleted successfully!"
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Could not delete Item with id=" + id
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Anchor is for navigation, do you want to use some other element type and have an onclick action instead?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `<a>` without `href`? What is your end goal with this? You can attach a click listener to any DOM element.

Comment: how can I give link to font awesome icon without href?